# Our Air desktop app has bitmaps - they look great on Mac and terrible on Win! Ideas?

Tags: windows, actionscript-3, bitmap, air, desktop

Here's the gist: we have an Air app that displays bitmaps at full screen, original size and scaled. On the Mac, these bitmaps look great (antialiased and smooth). On Windows (regardless of machine), they look pixelated and terrible.

We've updated Air and it still looks bad under the latest Air build. Is there something that we can do programmatically to fix this, or is there a platform issue that we don't know about?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to set the Smooth parameter as true?

```
var YOUR_BITMAP_OBJECT = Bitmap(YOUR_BITMAPDATA_OBJECT);
YOUR_BITMAP_OBJECT.smoothing = true;
```

Also be sure the export has the correct compression (recomendable more than 80%).

Check the resolution diference in Windows versus Mac, maybe in Windows it's higher.

Answer (score 0):

What is your current render mode? i suggest to set render mode to CPU.

Comment: In terms of performance and rendering vectors, CPU render-mode is pretty bad. Direct offers better performance, better vector rendering, and okay bitmap rendering. Adobe actively recommends using Direct. Is there a reason you recommend CPU?

Comment: no you are right direct is the best and recommended by adobe, but i am trying to make sure that your gpu hardware doesn't cause the problem, in my case when i changed the application render from gpu to cpu it give a better drawing quality, also make sure to set stage.quality to StageQuality.BEST.